# M-g M-g <nnn> to end of line (C-e)?

Tags: key-bindings, motion, line-numbers

I often have to use this sequence:

`M-g M-g <nnn> C-e`

to get to the *end* of a  particular line, for example to place a `%` or `\par` in TeX files.

Is there some way to combine this into, say (hypothetically):

`M-g M-X <nnn>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "M-g M-X")
                (lambda (linum)
                  (interactive "n")
                  (goto-line linum)
                  (end-of-line)))
```